# Voice typing is not working when talking onto Bletooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, voice-recognition

I'm trying to use the "Google Voice Typing" and Gboard dictation, both works fine.

However if I'm using my Bluetooth headset neither of them can recognise any words. Only if I hold the phone close enough.

It seems they are still using the internal mic. Is it possible possible to use the Bluetooth mics for these applications?

Note: I have enabled all these Bt related settings in Google > Settings > Voice.

I'm on Android 11.

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but.. have you tested the Bluetooth headset's mic on other apps and make sure it's working?

Comment: Yes, it works, I'm using it constantly for phone calls, voip calls, etc.